# django: Primary key issue when saving modelform into postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model with au autofield, which has the primary key as such:

```
class historical_recent_data(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created = True)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name= 'reference')
    Date = models.DateField()
    Quantity = models.FloatField(default=0)
    NetAmount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.reference
```

Now, when I want to input data into the db table with a form in template, Django tries to give the `id` field a 1 value resulting in the following error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dashboard2_historical_recent_data2_pkey1"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
```

there is more than 11,000 values in this db table, why django does not automatically generate the pk to be 11,001 when a new form is being posted into the table?

UPDATE: my original question is why the autofield  increment from 1 and not does not increment starting from the biggest pk value in the table.

Comment: You have an `id` and `Id` field? Please don't. Most databases have case insensitive matching of columns, so column `FOO` and `foo` are the same.

Comment: yes lol, this is a trial project, Id actually refers to a serial number of parts. sure it will cause issues later but so far, it holds as I experiment around, I don't think it is the root of the issue at hand, or is it?

Comment: Well I would strongly advice to give it another name, or at least specify a `db_column=...` parameter with a different value. Likely there is clash.

Comment: okok I give it a try

Comment: changing Id to something else did not make the trick Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score -1):

> just remove the id field.

```
class historical_recent_data(models.Model):
    # id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created = True)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name= 'reference')
    Date = models.DateField()
    Quantity = models.FloatField(default=0)
    NetAmount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.reference
```

Comment: Just tried it out, it does not change the output, i dont understand what can be wrong

Comment: comment this line 
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created = True)
and
delete database or database file. if you are using sqlite.
run the command 
1) python manage.py makemigrations
2) python manage.py migrate

if still it does not work.
also delete all files from migrations folder except __init.py file. the retry to makemigrattions and migrate

Comment: i use postgresql

Comment: delete the database and create on other one with the same name.
than follow those steps agaian

Comment: i have tried your suggestion and I still have the same issue